# Ansible won't let me add quotes to my variables when I try to use "blockinfile" and "block"

Tags: ansible

Using containers, I'm trying to create a `.bashrc` file with Python3 Ansible v0.2.4.2.0. I'm also using Ansible roles.

```
- name: Adding environment vars to .bashrc file
  blockinfile:
    path=/.bashrc
    insertafter: EOF
    block: |
      export VAR1={{ var1 }}
      export VAR2={{ var2 }}
      export VAR3={{ var3 }}
```

Where all 3 variables are defined in my main file, `play.yml`. So, let's say `var1` is equal to `"-a -b -c"` (including the quotes), `var2` is equal to `"d"` and `var3` is equal to `"e"`

Then after I run `play.yml`, my `.bashrc` file looks like:

```
export VAR1=-a -b -c
export VAR2=d
export VAR3=e
```

But what I really want is

```
export VAR1="-a -b -c"
export VAR2="d"
export VAR3="e"
```

If I don't have the quotes for `VAR1`, then running `source /.bashrc` gives me:

```
bash: export: `-a: not a valid identifier
bash: export: `-b: not a valid identifier
bash: export: `-c: not a valid identifier
```

I've tried this:

```
- name: Creating .bashrc file
  blockinfile:
    path=/.bashrc
    insertafter: EOF
    block: |
      export VAR1=\"{{ var1 }}\"
      export VAR2=\"{{ var2 }}\"
      export VAR3=\"{{ var3 }}\"
```

but that does not add quotes to my `.bashrc` file. I still get the same results. What can I do to add quotes? I've also tried adding `\"\"`, which adds exactly `\"\"` to the beginning of each line. So that doesn't work either when I try to run `source /.bashrc`

Comment: odd. Can you create a var named qq with a double quote as the value and use it there?

Answer (score 1):

Set your variables like this:

```
var1: '"fred"'
var2: '"barney"'
var3: '"wilma"'
```